# PHP speed: what is faster? if (isset ($foo)) OR if ($foo==true)

Tags: php, optimization, performance

I am just trying to optimize my code.
I need to prefill a form with data from a database, and I need to check if the variable exist to fill the text box (I don't like the `@` error hiding).
The form is really long, then I need to check multiple times if the variables exist.

What is faster of the following two?

- `if (isset ($item))`
- `if ($item_exists==true)`

Or even

- `if ($item_exists===true)`

Comment: you can get into trouble with `if ($foo==true)`, what if $foo is zero and that is valid?

Comment: The performance penalty for the == and === case is, an E_NOTICE error is being thrown because the variable does not exist.  Throwing errors is relatively expensive.  When you call isset(), no error is thrown if the variable does not exist.

Answer (score 32):

With a `for` loop repeating it 10000000 times the same script took:

- `if (isset ($item))` 2.25843787193
- `if ($item_exists==true)` 6.25483512878
- `if ($item_exists===true)` 5.99481105804

So I can tell `isset` surely is faster.

Comment: +1 for doing the benchmarking. It also shows that it makes no real difference - it's extremely rare for a PHP script to do something 10 million times, and usually, the database / file I/O overhead would massively increase the time needed even then.

Comment: what was $item_exists? I think the "==" might vary based on its type

Comment: To add to the numbers game: Either way is on the order of 0.0000001 seconds. Which means you'd have to do it around 1,000,000 times per page to be something the user would notice (assuming 0.1 seconds is what the user would notice).

In short, the sort of micro-optimization that will rarely, if ever, make a difference.

Comment: This is awhul performance related question and awful answer
such trifle things has nothing common with **optimization**
the only Pekka's answer makes sense

Answer (score 11):

In this case you shouldn’t ask about performance but about correctness first. Because `isset` does not behave like a boolean convertion and comparison to *true* (see [type comparison table](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)). Especially the values `""` (empty string), `array()` (empty array), `false`, `0`, and `"0"` (`0` as a string) are handled differently.

Comment: +1.  On top of the difference in comparison tables, using a comparison operator on an undeclared variable results in an E_NOTICE.

Answer (score 7):

I'm sure there is a performance difference; I'm sure it has been benchmarked somewhere; but I'm also sure it really doesn't matter at all for real-world purposes. Any achievable gain is in the milliseconds here, and what's much, much more important is the readability of the code, and the avoiding of warnings (which cost performance, whether output or not).

You will probably need `isset` if you can't be sure it's set at the time you access it. type-safe comparison `===` shouldn't be necessary if `$item_exists` always is a boolean, but it won't harm either. So depending on your situation, you may need

```
if ((isset($item)) and ($item_exists === true))
```

Comment: It's better to use `if(empty($item))` instead of that code.

Answer (score 1):

To answer though, most likely isset() and "===" will be fastest as they only check for one condition, where == checks for multiple conditions and be slower. I haven't officially tested this, but I think its right. @Pekka is also correct, if you are looking to optimize, these really aren't going to be where you do it. As it would probably take thousands of calls just to notice a few milliseconds of difference.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest the following alternatives:

```
if (@$item)
if (@$item_exists)
```

Answer (score -2):

There is only one way to optimize your code, called "profiling". First you got to know **what part of code** requires optimization. And only then run tests, find solutions, etc.

The "circling" approach from the Marcx's answer is awful too. If you want to test if any code makes a real difference, test it from the browser's point of view, using the [Apache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) benchmark utility.